# JavaFX css class style

Tags: java, html, css, javafx

How can I set a CSS style for a class which extends a JavaFX object?

```
public class DiagramPane extends ScrollPane implements IDiagramEditor {
    // .... Methods go here
}
```

I've tried the following ways in the main method:

```
public class DiagramPane extends ScrollPane implements IDiagramEditor {
    DiagramPane() {
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #f8ecc2;-fx-font-size: 8pt;");
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #f8ecc2;-fx-font-size: 8pt;");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add these lines to your css file

```
.diagram-pane {
    -fx-background-color: #f8ecc2;
    -fx-font-size: 8pt;
}
```

and set `DiagramPane` instance to use `diagram-pane` style class

```
diagramPane.getStyleClass().clear();
diagramPane.getStyleClass().add("diagram-pane");
```

Comment: does not answere question, i too am looking for a way to have a CLASS return a style - string, not include some css files

Answer (score 4):

**One of the possibilities is what you have mentioned to use [setStyle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setStyle-java.lang.String-)** **method of Node.**

```
public class MyScrollPane extends ScrollPane {

    public MyScrollPane(){
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
    }

}
```

**Another possibility to use a CSS stylesheet**

This one is the suggested approach, as it totally separates the CSS styling from the Java code.

Note: `MyScrollPane.css` is placed in the same directory as the class itself.

*MyScrollPane.java*

```
public class MyScrollPane extends ScrollPane {

    public MyScrollPane(){
        getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("MyScrollPane.css").toExternalForm());
    }

}
```

In this stylesheet you can overwrite the existing CSS classes of the ScrollPane like:

*MyScrollPane.css*

```
.scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: red, white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;
    -fx-padding: 2.0;
}
```

To check which classes exist for scroll pane in JavaFX you can read the [caspian.css](https://kenai.com/projects/javaone2010-s313389/sources/javaone-repository/content/ScubaDiving/src/scubadiving/caspian.css?rev=20). The base class for `ScrollPane` is `.scroll-pane`.

Also you can define new CSS classes and add them to your `ScrollPane`:

```
public class MyScrollPane extends ScrollPane {

    public MyScrollPane(){
        getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("MyScrollPane.css").toExternalForm());
        getStyleClass().add("red-border");
    }

}
```

And in CSS

```
.red-border {
    -fx-background-color: red, white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;
    -fx-padding: 2.0;
}
```

To learn about CSS styling in JavaFX: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm

Also you can check the CSS Reference Guide for JavaFX: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: can't u use setUserAgentStylesheet nowadays?