# HTML/CSS: How to make multiple 'versions' of an 'article' for different types of articles

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, web-applications

I made a chat application in Java, and am using javascript, HTML, and CSS for the front end. For the app you can send a public or a private message. The javascript grabs the message from a text box and sends it to the server, which then makes an HTML message out of it and returns it as a rendered article.

I want to have public and private messages be displayed in different colors so it's easy to distinguish between them.

This is the function that gets called to render a public message:

```
   private static String createHtmlMessageFromSender(String sender, String message) {
        return article(
                b(sender + " says:"),
                span(attrs(".timestamp"), new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())),
                p(message)
        ).render();
    }
```

This one gets called to render a private message:

```
private static String createHtmlMessageFromSenderPrivate(String sender, String message) {
    return article(
            b(sender + " says to you:"),
            span(attrs(".timestamp"), new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())),
            p(message)
    ).render();
}
```

I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS. Both private and public messages are being rendered as 'article's and put in a div object called 'chat.' I don't know if it's possible to make two different 'versions' of '#chat article' in my CSS file so that it can have one type of styling for private messages and one type for public messages. This seems like it would be a common thing to do but I can't find information about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Java guy, but it sounds like you want to give each new node you're rendering a class, and style it in CSS like so:

```
.firstClassName {
    color: red;
}

.secondClassName {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: How do you do that? I've never heard of a class in a CSS context (am a computer science student and had this project randomly assigned)

Comment: CSS doesn't use 'classes' in the way that PHP / Java do. Class is more a name for a 'class' of objects that you want to be styled in a similar way.

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_class.asp

Comment: Just been looking at how to assign CSS classes in Java and not sure how much help I can be. Here's this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499885/javafx-css-class-style

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of these options:

1) Using 2 different ids (like #chat and #privatechat) where you could set a different color for one or another in css.

2) Set a *style* attribute for each case e.g.

```
<div id="chat" style="background-color:#ababab">private</div>
```

or

```
<div id="chat" style="background-color:#cecece">public</div>
```

3) Use Sass (https://sass-lang.com/) to control your stylesheets. Sass allow you to use conditional statements in your stylesheet.

Please let me know if you need more HTML help.